# Overloading < operator in template

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm programming a binary tree class template. When I add a new node I check if the new one is less or greater than current.

I overloaded < and > operator in the class type (Object) and works properly but the template doesn't call the overloaded operator, instead uses the generated by the compiler.

> object.cc - Comparison between objects works outside the template

```
bool Object::operator<(const Object& par_other) const 
{
  printf("\n    <");
  return id_ < par_other.id_;  //assume that you compare the record based on a
}
```

EDIT 1: Added some requested code. Thx for the help :)

```
struct Node {
    T* value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
  };

template <class T> 
void BinaryTree<T>::add(T* par_T, Node* par_node) {
  if (par_node == nullptr) {
    par_node->left = nullptr;
    par_node->value = par_T;
    par_node->right = nullptr;

  } else {
    if (par_node->value == nullptr) {
      par_node->value = par_T;

    } else if (par_node->value > par_T) {
      if (!par_node->right) {
        par_node->right = createNode();
      }
      add(par_T, par_node->right);

    } else if (par_node->value < par_T) {
      if (!par_node->left) {
        par_node->left = createNode();
      }
      add(par_T, par_node->left);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Double check that you are comparing instances, not pointers, that is

Comment: provide the piece of code in which you are comparing the instances

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: You are comparing pointerd, for which you can't overload operators

Comment: How should i compare this?
   ¿  *(par_node->value) < (par_T)  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does a node have a `T*` instead of a `T`?

If you have a good reason to do that, then compare with:

`*par_T < *(par_node->value)`

and

`*(par_node->value) < *par_T`

Notice the use of `*` and notice I switched the sides rather than misuse `>`

If you didn't have a good reason to have a node contain a `T*` then get rid of the `*`s in this code (and correspondingly elsewhere) but still remember not to use `>`, `==`, `!=` etc.  They all can be inferred by results of `<` ( `a` is "equal to" `b` when both `a<b` and `b<a` are `false`)

You also need to fix more things than you asked about.  You seem generally confused about the nature of pointers.  An extreme example from your code:

```
  if (par_node == nullptr) {
    par_node->left = nullptr;
    par_node->value = par_T;
    par_node->right = nullptr;
  }
```

Think about what that code is doing!

Comment: It's working. Didn't notice I was comparing pointers. I use T* because I feel more comfortable working with pointers and this way the function do not create new copies of the Node